# SSRS How to hide a subreport if has error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, subreport

I currently have a tablix with only one column and row where I load my subreport.

The tablix has a group by employee id since i need to generate the same reporte for every employee on the company. The problem is, that there are some employees that given some special circumstances can't generate the subreport and insted of sending it blank it shows an error message about parameters.

Putting in numbers about 45 of my 200 employees generate that error, all of them for different reasons.

How can I detect if the subreport has an error and hide that page from showing on the report?

Comment: It might be easier to modify the sub-report to display nothing instead of throwing an error.

Comment: You need to code your dataset in such a way that it realises it will cause an error, and return a parameter that will hide the report.